# Implicit conversion not allowed, while loop

Tags: sql-server, while-loop, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to execute the query below and I keep getting this error:

Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spRptTenRentRolldbs1, Line 802 [Batch Start Line 3]
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

It looks like I am getting about 1 error per loop.

```
USE [DBs1]
GO

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) AS rownum, siteid INTO rowsiteRentRoll FROM dbo.sites

CREATE TABLE temptableRentRoll
(
    SiteID1 INT,
    LedgerID INT,
    sUnit VARCHAR (200),
    sSize VARCHAR (200),
    Area1 DECIMAL (19,2),
    UnitID INT,
    SiteID INT,
    EmployeeID INT ,
    UnitTypeID INT,
    UnitZoneID VARCHAR (200),
    MapRAID_Row VARCHAR (200),
    MapRAID_Aisle VARCHAR (200),
    sTrackingCode VARCHAR (200),
    sRFID VARCHAR (200),
    sGlobalUnitName VARCHAR (200),
    TransferredTo_sGlobalSiteNum VARCHAR (200),
    TransferredFrom_sGlobalSiteNum VARCHAR (200),
    dTransferred DATETIME ,
    TransferredBy_EmployeeID INT,
    sUnitName VARCHAR (200),
    iWalkThruOrder INT,
    iFloor INT,
    dcWidth INT,
    dcLength INT,
    dcMapTop VARCHAR (200),
    dcMapLeft VARCHAR (200),
    dcMapTheta VARCHAR (200),
    bMapReversWL VARCHAR (200),
    dcPushRate DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcStdRate DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcStdWeeklyRate DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcStdSecDep DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcStdLateFee DECIMAL (19,2),
    bPower INT,
    bClimate INT,
    bInside INT,
    bAlarm INT,
    bRentable INT,
    bRented INT,
    dCreated DATETIME,
    dDeleted DATETIME,
    sUnitNote VARCHAR (600),
    dUnitNote DATETIME,
    sOSSType VARCHAR (200),
    bCorporate VARCHAR (200),
    bMobile VARCHAR (200),
    dBuilt DATETIME,
    dFirstInService DATETIME,
    iMobileStatus VARCHAR (200),
    bDamaged VARCHAR (200),
    dDamaged DATETIME,
    bCollapsible VARCHAR (200),
    EmployeeID_BuiltBy VARCHAR (200),
    bPermanent VARCHAR (200),
    dUpdated DATETIME,
    uTS VARCHAR(200),
    OldPK INT,
    MarketID_Whse INT,
    sUnitDesc VARCHAR (200),
    iEntryLoc VARCHAR (200),
    dArchived DATETIME,
    bExcludeFromSqftReports VARCHAR (200),
    bExcludeFromWebsite VARCHAR (200),
    bNotReadyToRent VARCHAR (200),
    dcSchedRateMonthly DECIMAL (19,2),
    dSchedRateMonthStrt DATETIME,
    dcSchedRateWeekly  DECIMAL (19,2),
    dSchedRateWeeklyStrt DATETIME,
    iADA INT,
    iDoorType VARCHAR (200),
    iVehicleStorageAllowed VARCHAR (200),
    iDaysVacant VARCHAR (200),
    dcWebRate DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcWebPushRate DECIMAL (19,2),
    LockID VARCHAR (200),
    Area DECIMAL (19,2),
    sTaxExempt VARCHAR (200),
    sTenant VARCHAR (400),
    sCompany VARCHAR (400),
    iAnnivDays INT,
    dLeaseDate DATETIME,
    dcSecDep DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcStandardRate DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcRent DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcVar DECIMAL (19,2),
    dSchedRentStrt DATETIME,
    dcSchedRent DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcChargeBalance DECIMAL (19,2),
    dPaidThru DATETIME,
    dcPrePaidRentLiability DECIMAL (19,2),
    CreditCardID DECIMAL (19,2),
    dRentLastChanged DATETIME,
    DaysSame DATETIME,
    dSchedOut DATETIME,
    TenantID INT,
    sEmail VARCHAR (200),
    dcInsurPremium DECIMAL (19,2),
    dcPushRateAtMoveIn DECIMAL (19,2),
    iAutoBillType INT

)


DECLARE @enddate datetime
SET @enddate = DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))

DECLARE @maxrow INT
SET @maxrow = (SELECT COUNT(siteid) FROM rowsiteRentRoll)

DECLARE @row INT
SET @row = 1


WHILE(@row <= @maxrow)
BEGIN

DECLARE @siteidrow INT
SET @siteidrow = (SELECT siteid FROM rowsiteRentRoll WHERE rownum = @row)

INSERT INTO temptableRentRoll 
(
    SiteID1,
    LedgerID,
    sUnit,
    sSize,
    Area1,
    UnitID,
    SiteID,
    EmployeeID,
    UnitTypeID,
    UnitZoneID,
    MapRAID_Row,
    MapRAID_Aisle,
    sTrackingCode,
    sRFID,
    sGlobalUnitName,
    TransferredTo_sGlobalSiteNum,
    TransferredFrom_sGlobalSiteNum,
    dTransferred,
    TransferredBy_EmployeeID,
    sUnitName,
    iWalkThruOrder,
    iFloor,
    dcWidth,
    dcLength,
    dcMapTop,
    dcMapLeft,
    dcMapTheta,
    bMapReversWL,
    dcPushRate,
    dcStdRate,
    dcStdWeeklyRate,
    dcStdSecDep,
    dcStdLateFee,
    bPower,
    bClimate,
    bInside,
    bAlarm,
    bRentable,
    bRented,
    dCreated,
    dDeleted,
    sUnitNote,
    dUnitNote,
    sOSSType,
    bCorporate,
    bMobile,
    dBuilt,
    dFirstInService,
    iMobileStatus,
    bDamaged,
    dDamaged,
    bCollapsible,
    EmployeeID_BuiltBy,
    bPermanent,
    dUpdated,
    uTS,
    OldPK,
    MarketID_Whse,
    sUnitDesc,
    iEntryLoc,
    dArchived,
    bExcludeFromSqftReports,
    bExcludeFromWebsite,
    bNotReadyToRent,
    dcSchedRateMonthly,
    dSchedRateMonthStrt,
    dcSchedRateWeekly,
    dSchedRateWeeklyStrt,
    iADA,
    iDoorType,
    iVehicleStorageAllowed,
    iDaysVacant,
    dcWebRate,
    dcWebPushRate,
    LockID,
    Area,
    sTaxExempt,
    sTenant,
    sCompany,
    iAnnivDays,
    dLeaseDate,
    dcSecDep,
    dcStandardRate,
    dcRent,
    dcVar,
    dSchedRentStrt,
    dcSchedRent,
    dcChargeBalance,
    dPaidThru,
    dcPrePaidRentLiability,
    CreditCardID,
    dRentLastChanged,
    DaysSame,
    dSchedOut,
    TenantID,
    sEmail,
    dcInsurPremium,
    dcPushRateAtMoveIn,
    iAutoBillType
    )


EXEC dbo.spRptTenRentRolldbs1
        @SiteID = @siteidrow,
        @dEnd = @enddate,
        @Filter = '100'

SET @row = @row + 1

END
```

I've read that this can happen if the table definition does not match what is being inserted, I checked that and everything matches.

At this point I have to assume that I miss-classified the data type for one of the columns. I am just going off of what I can see in the output, several of the columns only contain NULL values so I am not sure what they are, had to make an educated guess.

Unfortunately this is utilizing a very complex SP which references all kinds of other functions and SP's. I'm trying to avoid tracing back each column to the origin to determine the data type.

How can I read the error to determine which column is the issue? I tried going to line 802 in the query (doesn't exist) and the stored procedure (doesn't make any sense). I'm thinking this may be complicated by the loop?

**UPDATE**

I was able to pull all of the datatypes returned by the SP using this:

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'dbo.spRptTenRentRolldbs1'
```

I updated my code to use the exact data types returned by the above:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY siteid) AS rownum, siteid INTO rowsiteRentRoll FROM dbo.sites

CREATE TABLE temptableRentRoll
(
    SiteID1 int,
    LedgerID int,
    sUnit nvarchar(6),
    sSize varchar(4),
    Area1 money,
    UnitID int,
    SiteID int,
    EmployeeID int,
    UnitTypeID int,
    UnitZoneID int,
    MarketID_Whse int,
    MapRAID_Row int,
    MapRAID_Aisle int,
    sTrackingCode nvarchar(30),
    sRFID nvarchar(30),
    sGlobalUnitName nvarchar(30),
    TransferredTo_sGlobalSiteNum nvarchar(20),
    TransferredFrom_sGlobalSiteNum nvarchar(20),
    dTransferred datetime,
    TransferredBy_EmployeeID int,
    sUnitName nvarchar(6),
    iWalkThruOrder int,
    iFloor int,
    dcWidth money,
    dcLength money,
    dcMapTop money,
    dcMapLeft money,
    dcMapTheta money,
    bMapReversWL bit,
    dcPushRate money,
    dcStdRate money,
    dcStdWeeklyRate money,
    dcStdSecDep money,
    dcStdLateFee money,
    bPower bit,
    bClimate bit,
    bInside bit,
    bAlarm bit,
    bRentable bit,
    bRented bit,
    dCreated datetime,
    dDeleted datetime,
    sUnitNote nvarchar(150),
    dUnitNote datetime,
    sOSSType nvarchar(10),
    bCorporate bit,
    bMobile bit,
    dBuilt datetime,
    dFirstInService datetime,
    iMobileStatus int,
    bDamaged bit,
    dDamaged datetime,
    bCollapsible bit,
    EmployeeID_BuiltBy int,
    sUnitDesc nvarchar(50),
    iEntryLoc int,
    bExcludeFromSqftReports bit,
    bExcludeFromWebsite bit,
    bNotReadyToRent bit,
    iADA int,
    iDoorType int,
    iVehicleStorageAllowed int,
    dArchived datetime,
    bPermanent bit,
    dUpdated datetime,
    uTS binary (8),
    OldPK int,
    dcSchedRateMonthly money,
    dSchedRateMonthStrt datetime,
    dcSchedRateWeekly money,
    dSchedRateWeeklyStrt datetime,
    iDaysVacant int,
    dcWebRate money,
    dcWebPushRate money,
    LockID int,
    Area money,
    sTaxExempt nvarchar(1),
    sTenant nvarchar(100),
    sCompany nvarchar(80),
    iAnnivDays int,
    dLeaseDate datetime,
    dcSecDep money,
    dcStandardRate money,
    dcRent money,
    dcVar money,
    dSchedRentStrt datetime,
    dcSchedRent money,
    dcChargeBalance money,
    dPaidThru datetime,
    dcPrePaidRentLiability numeric(38,4),
    CreditCardID int,
    dRentLastChanged datetime,
    DaysSame int,
    dSchedOut datetime,
    TenantID int,
    sEmail nvarchar(100),
    dcInsurPremium money,
    dcPushRateAtMoveIn money,
    iAutoBillType int



)


DECLARE @enddate datetime
SET @enddate = DATEADD(ss, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))

DECLARE @maxrow INT
SET @maxrow = (SELECT COUNT(siteid) FROM rowsiteRentRoll)

DECLARE @row INT
SET @row = 1


WHILE(@row <= @maxrow)
BEGIN

DECLARE @siteidrow INT
SET @siteidrow = (SELECT siteid FROM rowsiteRentRoll WHERE rownum = @row)

INSERT INTO temptableRentRoll 
(
    SiteID1,
    LedgerID,
    sUnit,
    sSize,
    Area1,
    UnitID,
    SiteID,
    EmployeeID,
    UnitTypeID,
    UnitZoneID,
    MapRAID_Row,
    MapRAID_Aisle,
    sTrackingCode,
    sRFID,
    sGlobalUnitName,
    TransferredTo_sGlobalSiteNum,
    TransferredFrom_sGlobalSiteNum,
    dTransferred,
    TransferredBy_EmployeeID,
    sUnitName,
    iWalkThruOrder,
    iFloor,
    dcWidth,
    dcLength,
    dcMapTop,
    dcMapLeft,
    dcMapTheta,
    bMapReversWL,
    dcPushRate,
    dcStdRate,
    dcStdWeeklyRate,
    dcStdSecDep,
    dcStdLateFee,
    bPower,
    bClimate,
    bInside,
    bAlarm,
    bRentable,
    bRented,
    dCreated,
    dDeleted,
    sUnitNote,
    dUnitNote,
    sOSSType,
    bCorporate,
    bMobile,
    dBuilt,
    dFirstInService,
    iMobileStatus,
    bDamaged,
    dDamaged,
    bCollapsible,
    EmployeeID_BuiltBy,
    bPermanent,
    dUpdated,
    uTS,
    OldPK,
    MarketID_Whse,
    sUnitDesc,
    iEntryLoc,
    dArchived,
    bExcludeFromSqftReports,
    bExcludeFromWebsite,
    bNotReadyToRent,
    dcSchedRateMonthly,
    dSchedRateMonthStrt,
    dcSchedRateWeekly,
    dSchedRateWeeklyStrt,
    iADA,
    iDoorType,
    iVehicleStorageAllowed,
    iDaysVacant,
    dcWebRate,
    dcWebPushRate,
    LockID,
    Area,
    sTaxExempt,
    sTenant,
    sCompany,
    iAnnivDays,
    dLeaseDate,
    dcSecDep,
    dcStandardRate,
    dcRent,
    dcVar,
    dSchedRentStrt,
    dcSchedRent,
    dcChargeBalance,
    dPaidThru,
    dcPrePaidRentLiability,
    CreditCardID,
    dRentLastChanged,
    DaysSame,
    dSchedOut,
    TenantID,
    sEmail,
    dcInsurPremium,
    dcPushRateAtMoveIn,
    iAutoBillType
    )


EXEC dbo.spRptTenRentRolldbs1
        @SiteID = @siteidrow,
        @dEnd = @enddate,
        @Filter = '100'

SET @row = @row + 1

END
```

And somehow I am still getting the same error message in a different batch start line:

***Msg 257, Level 16, State 3, Procedure spRptTenRentRolldbs1, Line 802 [Batch Start Line 6]
Implicit conversion from data type datetime to int is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.***

As far as I can tell this should be impossible, I pulled the exact data types returned by the SP and made them my table definition.. how is this possible???

Comment: You are trying to insert a datetime into a column that is of type `int`. You need to go through your code and find where the int columns are and then see if you are inserting int into all of them, the error states you are not.

Comment: The error message states that the problem is in spRptTenRentRolldbs1. You need to find the relevant part of that proc, and paste it here. Otherwise your question is off-topic as no-one will be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: Stop making assumptions - the loop is irrelevant for the most part. Just print those parameter values supplied to the procedure immediately before you call the procedure. That will generate a long list of values but the last printed set is the one producing the error in your procedure. With that you can just call the procedure directly, making debugging a bit easier. And yes - you will need to go through that complex procedure.

Comment: Is there no way to use the error message to locate the issue in the stored procedure? Like I said, line 802 has nothing to do with the error I am seeing.

Comment: Line numbering is notoriously poor in error messages. Short answer - no.

Comment: Updated with what I found and cross checked. Still don't see an error. Is it possible that the data types the error message is describing are inaccurate also? Could it be a money to decimal issue?

Comment: Figured it out. Very bizarre and frustrating. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The succinct answer for anyone else who has a similar problem...

There ended up being something wrong with my data types. I do not know specifically what the issue was because I found a way to over-write all of my data labels with labels directly from the SP.

**I ran this to get a list of all data types returned by the SP:**

```
EXEC sp_describe_first_result_set N'dbo.spRptTenRentRolldbs1'
```

I then dumped the result set into excel to quickly recreate my table creation code. Then I modified my query to include the new data types and that "ultimately" solved my problem.

I say "ultimately" because I ran into an additional issue where I accidentally put one of the columns out of order and that resulted in the same error message I was originally receiving - so it appears that this particular error does not necessarily mean you have a data type conversion issue.

**It seems that it could also mean there is something wrong with the table creation/definition structure.**